# restrict a minimum order using php

Tags: php, minimum

I'm creating an eCommerce website using HTML and PHP. I have a table named "products" in the database.
the minimum order values of the products are all saved in this table.
I have an admin panel to set the minimum order for that particular product. The quantity of the minimum order of each and every product was saved in the MySQL database. The minimum order value of that particular product is set by the admin according to the amount of availability of the product. There are no constraints for the admin to set the minimum order in the admin panel.

My question is how do I get the minimum order(`$row['moq']`) quantity from the "product" table in the database so that the orders(`cart_qty`) from the users will be restricted to a certain amount that has been set from the Admin Panel using **minimum attributes**.

These are the codes that I used to require users to add the quantity that they wanted to order:

```html
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<form action="store_items.php" method="post">
  <div class="col-12 form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <input type="number" name="cart_qty" step="0.01" value="1" class="form-control text-center" </div>
        <div class="col-9">
          <input class="btn btn-block addtocart" type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="addtocart" <?php if($row[ 'product_status']==0 ) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?> >
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is where I add the minimum order from the admin panel. `moq` is the entity of the minimum order in the product table.

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Minimum Order Quantity*</label>
    <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter minimum order quantity" name="moq" value="<?php echo $row['moq'];?>" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the `$row['moq']` to restrict the number of orders in `cart_qty`. I know the method of using the **minimum attributes** but how do I get the values from of the `moq` in the product table to restrict the input value of `cart_qty` in the user page.

I'm not using any eCommerce platform (eg. WooCommerce) to build my website. Just a pure HTML, PHP, and JavaScript.

Comment: Have you thought about using the `onChange` event and then a little bit of Javascript?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i did think of using Javascript. But I'm not sure how should I do it. Can you show me a code demo on how to implement the `onchange` event that you mentioned?

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onChange` event to restrict the value using Javascript.

```
<input type="number" onchange="restrictValue(this, 10, 30);">
```

Then in Javascript you do:

```
function restrictValue(inputElement, minimum, maximum)
{
    let value = inputElement.value;
    if (value < minimum) value = minimum;
    if (value > maximum) value = maximum;
    inputElement.value = value;
}
```

You could use the `onKeyUp` to constantly correct any value entered, but that could be quite disruptive and irritating.

Comment: can i know what `restrictValue(this, 10, 30);` this does?

Comment: Test the code in a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and you can see what it does.

Comment: Here's one: https://jsfiddle.net/2watcofy/ (tip: Press the "Run" button...)

Comment: Another way to answer your question is: "It calls the given Javascript function when the input was changed.".